# missing of domain and controller under grails-app in GGTS 2.2.1

Tags: grails

suddenly there is a missing of domain, controller and someother folders in my project in GGTS 2.2.1 my imported project looks like following folder
    https://issuetracker.springsource.com/secure/attachment/13369/After%20Import%20followed%20by%20Update%20Project%20Configuration.jpg

[image]

Comment: I can see them in the snapshot at the top. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Make sure you're using the Grails perspective in GGTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand the problem is that you don't see some folders (eg domain, controllers, ...) in project explorer. This happend to me once too.

The problem was that the imported projected didn't have .classpath file and when you were importing the project grails made one for you.

The solution is to copy-paste the original .classpath file or if you don't have the original try to create it from another project.